# scipy.optimize.curve_fit can't fit an upside down gaussian

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting, gaussian

I'm trying to fit a line to an upside down gaussian distribution using scipy.optimize.curve_fit. It works perfectly to fit a traditional gaussian, but wont fit a gaussian with the sign flipped, and instead will always output a straight line.

I've also tried constraining my gaussian function so that the variable 'a' is always negative but this does not solve the problem. Specifying -max(y) instead of max(y) also does not seem to help.

```
import scipy
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import statsmodels.api as sm
from scipy import asarray as ar,exp

def fitdata(x, y):
    mean = sum(x * y) / sum(y)
    sigma = np.sqrt(sum(y * (x - mean) ** 2) / sum(y))

    def guassianfunc(xVar, a, b, c):
        return a * exp(-(xVar - b) ** 2 / (2 * c ** 2))

    popt, _ = scipy.optimize.curve_fit(guassianfunc, x, y, p0=[max(y), mean,         sigma])
    return guassianfunc(np.arange(1, 6, 1), *popt)


x = np.array((1,2,3,4,5))
f, ((ax1, ax2)) = plt.subplots(2, sharex='col', sharey='row')
y = np.array((1, 2, 3, 2, 1))
ax1.plot(x, y, color='black')
ax1.plot(x, fitdata(x, y), linewidth=2, label='Fit')
y = np.array((3, 2, 1, 2, 3))
ax2.plot(x, y, color='black')
ax2.plot(x, fitdata(x, y), linewidth=2, label='Fit')
plt.legend()
```

[image: output]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's because your second line would require an offset parameter maybe? i.e. your `guassianfunc` can make an upside down bell-curve provided it's below the x-axis. For example:

```
y = np.array((3, 2, 1, 2, 3))-4
ax2.plot(x, y, color='black')
ax2.plot(x, fitdata(x, y), linewidth=2, label='Fit')
```

Try adding in a 4th param like this

```
def fitdata(x, y):
    mean = sum(x * y) / sum(y)
    sigma = np.sqrt(sum(y * (x - mean) ** 2) / sum(y))

    def guassianfunc(xVar, a, b, c, d):
        return a * exp(-(xVar - b) ** 2 / (2 * c ** 2)) + d

    popt, _ = scipy.optimize.curve_fit(guassianfunc, x, y, p0=[max(y), mean,         sigma,0])
    return guassianfunc(x, *popt)
```

This also reduces your error significantly.

Comment: Just make sure it make sense for your application to have that extra parameter